# How to add a watch expression in Safari 6.1 Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, css, debugging, safari

I can't figure out how to do this.  I've seen screenshots of earlier versions (pre Safari 6, I believe) showing a "Watch Expressions" section, like there is in the Chrome tools.

For example [Older Safari Devlopment Tools Screenshot](https://www.webkit.org/blog-files/inspector/breakpoints.png):

[image: Screen]

I don't see this in the Safari 6.1 I'm trying to debug my JavaScript code on.  I see "With Object Properties", "Local Variables", and "Global Variables;" but no way to add a custom watch expression.

Thanks,

Eric

Answer (score 1):

Safari 6.1 hasn't watch expression option. But;

> At the bottom of the debugging window there is one more down arrow
>   icon near continue script execution icon. Clicking on the icon you
>   will get one console and you can see the value of the expressions you
>   are interested in.

Hope this helps you a bit.